# Rally Portfolio Apps?

Tags: sdk, rally

I am looking for examples of custom apps in Rally that manipulate the new Portfolio object recently released. At a basic level I would like to display Portfolio objects using the Cardboard Component. Is that possible, are there any examples out yet. The current SDK doesn't reference the new Portfolio object that I can find.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2010 Rally Software Development Corp. All rights reserved -->
<html>
<head>
   <title>App Example: Card Board Custom Styling</title>
   <meta name="Name" content="App Example: Card Board Custom Styling" />
   <meta name="Vendor" content="ADSK - Rally Software" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.26/sdk.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function onLoad() {
       var cardboard;

       var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
'__PROJECT_OID__',
'__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
'__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
       var cardboardConfig = {
         types: ["PortfolioItem", "HierarchicalRequirement"],
         attribute: "InvestmentCategory",
         fetch:"Name,FormattedID,Owner,ObjectID"
       };

       cardboard = new rally.sdk.ui.CardBoard(cardboardConfig, rallyDataSource);
       cardboard.display(dojo.body());
     }
     rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);

   </script>
   <style type="text/css">
     /*Make cards have bold text on a white background*/
     .cardboard .cardContent {
       background-color:#fff;
       font-weight:bold;
     }

     /*Make column headers smaller and green*/
     .cardboard .columnHeader {
       color: #6AB17D;
       font-size:12px;
     }

     /*Hide the owner avatar*/
     .cardboard .cardOwner {
       display:none;
     }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a cardboard using PortfolioItems you can take the example found [here](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/card-board) and make some minor adjustments. 
First you will need to change

```
types : ["Defect", "HierarchicalRequirement"],
```

to be

```
types : ["PortfolioItem"],
```

you will also need to change the attribute to one of the attributes on your portfolio item object. 
The list of attributes can be found [here.](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/body.jsp#PortfolioItem) An attribute that is common to all Portfolio Items is InvestmentCategory. So you would change line

```
attribute: "ScheduleState",
```

into

```
attribute: "InvestmentCategory",
```